# Can TOP questions on the landing page filter on tags from my profile?

Tags: feature-request, filtering, question-lists, homepage

Could we have an option to list on the *top* questions on the landing page related to tags in my profile. Stack Overflow seems to know what tags and skills I have. I'm only interested in seeing top questions related to my tags. For example, a question like 'Where should I start with my OPC-UA client?' is not relevant to me - I don't even know what it is.

I think if you could add another tab or option to limit to 'my tags' or 'my interests'. At the moment I think you can set up a filter - but why should I when Stack Overflow already knows what tags I'm interested in?

Comment: They just recently (within the last couple of months) enhanced  the filtering tools so you have even more ability to customize your own views. Wouldn't it make sense to try out those capabilities first before asking for the system to do it for you? The system won't know if the technologies you work with change tomorrow with a new project but you will and can then adjust yourself

Comment: Just a suggestion , plenty of ways to work out what my current technologies are what i've been viewing and posting - actually there is a treasure trove of data..there ..all the big sites are are using machine learning suggestions.. they probably know more about what i like than I do..;) as you say my technologies change I would be forever updating my tags but they would already 'know'.